# HTML element height computation rules

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why a `<div>` in my HTML code is being taken out of its container height computation, despite it having a non-zero height and not being absolutely positioned.

I've tried simplifying the code and reproducing the problem in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucrus/nm348hyj/26/), but I couldn't reproduce it there, so it seems to me my only choice is to let you look at the [real code](https://vacancyshop.virtualbit.it/).

The problem is that when you shrink the window just below 768 pixels of width (which is a breakpoint in my CSS) the `<div class="vs-month-timepicker-container">`, that contains the calendar and the timepicker, gets a computed height that does not include the timepicker (heck, it does not even include the full calendar), so it happens the `<div class="wpv-booking-option-title wpv-booking-accommodation-title">` below it, that contains the text "Which accommodation do you want?" overlaps the calendar and the timepicker.

Can you help me understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `flex-wrap: wrap;` of the element `.wpv-calendar-wrapper`and the height is okay.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks, but can you please help me understand why I can't reproduce the problem in my jsfiddle? The `flex-wrap: wrap` is there too.